# Android Studio Opencv - face detection sample

Tags: opencv, android-ndk

I'm student. I used Android Studio in new version, because I wanted to compile the face detection sample of Opencv library. 
At first problem, I didn't resolve the ndk path.

Show that error:

> Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':openCVSamplefacedetection:compileDebugNdk'.
>
> > NDK not configured. Download the NDK from http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/.Then add
> >     ndk.dir=path/to/ndk in local.properties. (On Windows, make sure you
> >     escape backslashes, e.g. C:\ndk rather than C:\ndk)

so I download the ndk and add the path like this.

`ndk.dir=d\:\\android-ndk-r10e`

Then, the new error is showing:

> Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':openCVSamplefacedetection:compileDebugNdk'.
>
> > A problem occurred starting process 'command 'd:\android-ndk-r10e\ndk-build.cmd'

Some people say that please add the sourceset.main in build.gradle, so I add the source code.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "org.opencv.samples.facedetect"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 22

        ndk {
            moduleName "detection_based_tracker"
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':openCVLibrary2410')
}
```

Finally built complete but my phone showed "FaceDetecter is stopped" and exit the app.
Don't you know the problem? I really don't know about Opencv's open source.

Comment: The solution is to delete the `jni` directory

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution to try it out with Task NdkCompile into your [build.gradle](https://github.com/egomez99/OPENCV_FaceDetection/blob/master/app/build.gradle#L24) file.

Also I do not think you need to add OPENCV as a dependency instead simply add JNI directories to configuration file as noted above (the jniLibs.srcDir is mapped to the proper location).

I know this question was asked 6 months ago, but I hope isn't late or others may find it useful for quick troubleshooting.

Best of luck.